# An exercise on nuclear maps in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Definition 2.1.1 Let $A, B$ be the C*-algebra, a map $\theta: A\rightarrow B$ is called **nuclear** if there exist contractive completely positive maps $\phi_{n}: A\rightarrow M_{k(n)}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\psi_{n}:M_{k(n)}(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow B$ such that 
$$||\psi_{n}\circ\phi_{n}(a)-\theta(a)||\rightarrow0$$
for all $a\in A$.

Then, there is an exercise below( I do not know how to do the exercise):

**Exercise 2.1.1** Show that $\theta:A \rightarrow B$ is nuclear if and only if for each finite set $F\subset A$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there exsit $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and contractive completely positive maps $\phi: A\rightarrow M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, $\psi:M_{n}(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow B$ such that $||\theta(a)-\psi\circ\phi(a)||<\varepsilon$ for all $a\in F$.

I suppose the "if" is clear from the definition. But how to prove the "only if"? I guess we need to use the finite set to construct a sequence of contractive completely positive map (just as in the definition.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the net $$\mathcal F=\{(F,t):\ F\subset A\,\text{ finite},\ t>0\},$$
ordered by $(F_1,t_1)\leq (F_2,t_2)$ if $F_1\subset F_2$, $t_1\geq t_2$. For each $\alpha=(F,t)\in\mathcal F$, there exist $n_\alpha\in\mathbb N$ and $\phi_\alpha:A\to M_{n_\alpha}(\mathbb C)$, $\psi_\alpha:M_{n_\alpha}(\mathbb C)\to A$ such that 
$$\|\psi_\alpha\circ\phi_\alpha(a)-\theta(a)\|<t,\ \ a\in F.$$
This net satisfies the requirement, then. For if $\varepsilon>0$ and $a\in A$ are given, we can choose $(F,\varepsilon)\in\mathcal F$ with $a\in F$, and then $\|\psi_\alpha\circ\phi_\alpha(a)-\theta(a)\|<\varepsilon$. And if $\beta\geq\alpha$, then $\beta=(F',s)$ with $F\subset F'$, $s\leq \varepsilon$, so 
$$
\|\psi_\beta\circ\phi_\beta(a)-\theta(a)\|<s<\varepsilon.
$$ 
We have shown that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\alpha_0\in\mathcal F$ such that, for any $\alpha\geq\alpha_0$, $\|\psi_\alpha\circ\phi_\alpha(a)-\theta(a)\|<\varepsilon$. That is,
$$
\lim_\alpha\|\psi_\alpha\circ\phi_\alpha(a)-\theta(a)\|=0.
$$

Comment: Do you use the condition that $F$ is finite ?

Comment: Yes. It is the hypothesis; only for finite sets you can find $\phi$, $\phi$ such that $\|\psi\circ\phi(a)-\theta(a)\|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: So you mean, for a fix finite set $F$, the $\varepsilon$ is corresponding to $F$, not arbitrary?

Comment: If you change either $F$ or $\varepsilon$, the maps will,be different.

Comment: In Exercise 2.1.1 above, if $F$ is an arbitrary set (without the assumption finite), the conclusion is still hold?

Comment: If you allow all sets, then you can take $F=A$ and there is nothing to prove. The point is to have a class of somewhat "small" sets where you can still test the condition.